# How to Append Multiple Json objects into single consolidated Json output object

Tags: python, json, append

I have two datasets as following and which are in Json format.

Emp_DT = json.dumps({'Employee_Details': [j1]}, indent=2, sort_keys=True)

Emp_HR = json.dumps({'Employee_HR_Hierarchy': [j2]}, indent=2, sort_keys=True)

Now i want to combine these two to have a single Json output with Object name "Employee".

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eufV.png)

Below are the two datasets which I want to combine together to get a consolidated JSon output

print(Emp_DT)

```
"Employee_Details": 
{
   "Name": "John Smith",
    "Age": 32,
    "Department": "Sales",
    "Salary": 30000,
    "DOJ": 12-06-2020
}
```

print(Emp_HR)

```
  "Employee_HR_Hierarchy": 
  {
    "Emp Name": "John Smith",
    "1st Manager Name": "Richard",
    "2nd Manager Name": "Paul"
  }
```

Comment: You can form a dictionary object as you want and then do JSON dumps on the final dictionary object.

Comment: you can use `dict.update()` in this case

Comment: Is this intended to be multiple data structures, or are you trying to make one large data structure? Also, it looks like `j2` is the same variable being dumped to each of the json strings in your code above. Is that actually supposed to be different data?

Comment: I have updated the variable, Please check it, hope now it's more precise 
The expected output is also added. click the link to see the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
import json

Emp_DT = {
            "Name": "John Smith",
            "Age": 32,
            "Department": "Sales",
            "Salary": 30000,
            "DOJ": "12-06-2020"
}

Emp_HR = {
            "Emp Name": "John Smith",
            "1st Manager Name": "Richard",
            "2nd Manager Name": "Paul"
}

emp1 = {
        "Employee_Details": Emp_DT,
        "Employee_HR_Hierarchy": Emp_HR
}

emps= {}
emps["Employee"] = emp1

emps_json_string = json.dumps(emps, indent=4)
print(emps_json_string)
```

Produces this output:

```
{
    "Employee": {
        "Employee_Details": {
            "Name": "John Smith",
            "Age": 32,
            "Department": "Sales",
            "Salary": 30000,
            "DOJ": "12-06-2020"
        },
        "Employee_HR_Hierarchy": {
            "Emp Name": "John Smith",
            "1st Manager Name": "Richard",
            "2nd Manager Name": "Paul"
        }
    }
}
```

Which is what you have asked for (?)

---

In addition, I would recommend formatting the code with meaningful names and a logical structure. For example, since the data here is of one employee, I would have named `Emp_DT` as `employee_1_details` and `Emp_HR` as `employee_1_HR`. And when saving it to the dictionary of all employees, it is probably better to go for `emps["employee_1"] = emp1` instead of `emps["Employee"] = emp1`.

Finally, I would recommend reading [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) when you have time.

Comment: Yes, This is what i was looking for. Thanks a lot :)
Sure, i will read this https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/